# Running all unit tests in nant, even if some fail!

Tags: unit-testing, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I want my unit tests to run regardless of there being a failure. I want to know how many are failing not just the first one, so I don't go through the build, fail, fix and build again cycle. Also, it is the responsibility of an other team to fix some tests so I want to know our are ok.

So in Nant, I've added the following in a target for the unit tests, as failonerror is false it runs all the tests, but does not fail the build.

```
<nunit2 failonerror="false" haltonfailure="false"> 
    <test appconfig="tests.config">
        <assemblies basedir="${test.dir}">
           <include name="SomeTests.dll" />
        </assemblies>
    </test>
</nunit2>
```

At the end of the run, Nant reports

```
1 non-fatal error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I want to check the non-fatal error count, if it is more than 0, I want to do something like this...

```
<fail message="Failures reported in unit tests."
      unless="report.errors == 0" />
```

except I don't know how to get the error count......does anyone know how?

Comment: I don't know nant at all, but what happens, when you set failonerror to true and only haltonfailure to false?

Comment: The build fails after the first unit test fails....:(

Comment: I'd recommend separating the "other team" tests from your tests on the CI server. You could use separate test assemblies, NUnit categories, etc. For your tests, if you run the unit tests locally before checking in you can avoid breaking the build. You want fast tests and a fast fail/fix cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that dropping [`<nunit2>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/nunit2.html) in favor of [`<exec>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) might be [a good idea anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2806287/38029), in Your special case the `<exec>` task can solve the problem:

```
<exec
  program="C:\dev\tools\NUnit\2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe"
  resultproperty="exec.nunit.result"
  failonerror="false">
  <arg file="C:\foo\bar.dll" />
</exec>
<if test="${int::parse(exec.nunit.result) != 0}">
  <!-- fail, print number of failures etc. -->
</if>
```