# Pure Virtual Method Called when the program is at nunit2 task of nant

Tags: nant

I am using `<nunit2>` task in NAnt and testing a .NET application.

I get this popup always saying

> R6025 Pure Virtual Method called.

Followed by

> Nant.exe stopped working.

I am unable to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Find my answer on general problems with `<nunit2>` task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171612/38029). I would prefer `<exec>` task since `<nunit2>` is outdated. Perhaps this will solve your problem as well.